# How to filter indices from elastic

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have a list of indices:

```
log$org$2018
log$org$2019_v2
log$org$2021_v5
log$org$2019
log$org_test$2020_v3
log$org_test$2019_v2
log$org_test$2021_v5
log$org$2019_v3
```

I want to keep only the following indices:

```
log$org$2018
log$org$2019_v2
log$org$2021_v5
log$org$2019
log$org$2019_v3
```

i.e: filter out indices that doesn't match `log$org$*` format

I'm using `get` function to get the indices and use regex to match the indices I want), but I get None.

**Code**

```
from elasticsearch6 import Elasticsearch

elasticsearch = Elasticsearch()
elasticsearch.indices.get(index=f"log$org$*")
```

**Logs**

```
Starting new HTTP connection (1): elasticsearch:9200
elasticsearch:9200 "GET /log%24org%24* HTTP/1.1" 200 2
GET elasticsearch:9200/log%24org%24* [status:200 request:0.010s]
> None
```

I assume its because the indices are composed of $ sign and it seems to cause the issue. I've also tried to escape $ chars but it still doesn't get any indices..

Would like your help on this :)

Comment: add an alias for the indices you want it can solve but I don't know if you just want a solution via regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to query via CLI, the solution is to use HEX instead of special characters..

As I saw in the logs, elastic parse special chars to HEX (i.e: $ -> %24)

`GET elasticsearch:9200/log%24org%24* [status:200 request:0.010s]`

Hence, the only thing I needed to do is replacing it in the query

Filtering indices by regex via `get` is by using $ as is..

Pretty annoying they haven't mentioned this in their docs..

Thanks who made an effort on this!

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

I believe you have an issue with your string interpolation.
What is the value for the `org` variable ?

You do not need to escape the `$` char

## To test

```json
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"log$org$2018"}}
{"index":"log$org$2018"}
{"index":{"_index":"log$org$2019_v2"}}
{"index":"log$org$2019_v2"}
{"index":{"_index":"log$org$2021_v5"}}
{"index":"log$org$2021_v5"}
{"index":{"_index":"log$org$2019"}}
{"index":"log$org$2019"}
{"index":{"_index":"log$org_test$2020_v3"}}
{"index":"log$org_test$2020_v3"}
{"index":{"_index":"log$org_test$2019_v2"}}
{"index":"log$org_test$2019_v2"}
{"index":{"_index":"log$org_test$2021_v5"}}
{"index":"log$org_test$2021_v5"}
{"index":{"_index":"log$org$2019_v3"}}
{"index":"log$org$2019_v3"}

GET /log$org$*/
```

Will return

```json
{
  "log$org$2018": {
  },
  "log$org$2019": {
  },
  "log$org$2019_v2": {
  },
  "log$org$2019_v3": {
  },
  "log$org$2021_v5": {
  }
}
```

And when queried with python

```py
org = "org"
es.indices.get(index=f'log${org}$*')
```

I get the same result.

Comment: Assume "org" is the value, and I get None when sending this request
`GET /log%24org%24* [status:200 request:0.010s]
> None`

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error. There must be something more.  Where do you get this `GET /log%24org%24* [status:200 request:0.010s] > None` ? My python code works correctly

Comment: These logs are coming from `elasticsearch6` client library, I've added more context to the question

Comment: which version of the stack are you using ?

Comment: `elasticsearch6` i.e 6